# Botframework QnAMaker save state and log to app insights

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework

I need to save the previous question and answer so that I can capture feedback from the user for the question answered by the QnAMaker. How do I access the conversation state in [**QnAMakerBaseDialog**](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/49.qnamaker-all-features/dialogs/qnamakerBaseDialog.js) and how do I log it to app insights/telemetry?

P.S. Wish this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-telemetry-qnamaker?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) had code for Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

So in order to access the conversation state I had to pass it from index.js.
It should've been passed down in the first place.

Anyways I was able to work around it.